# Adding private key to a distribution certificate

Tags: xcode

I'm on a development team and I just tried to deploy a build to TestFlight. I got the error "...has iOS Distribution Certificate but its private key is not installed." The team's creator sent me his private key but I can't figure out how to then use this to validate the certificates so I can deploy a build. Do I need more than just his password? What's the next step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Keychain Access app and find your development certificate (its beneath the Certificates tab on the left). Click the arrow beside the certificate to reveal your private key. Replace that private key (it probably says your name) with the private key that he sent you.